# Image of a simple closed curve under a bijection

Tags: complex-analysis

If a function $f$ is a bijection, and $\gamma$ is a simple, closed curve, then is $f(\gamma) = \gamma'$ also simple and closed? My textbook asserts that it is, and then asks (why?). Does the one-to-one property of $f$ explain the lack of self-intersection, and the onto property explain the closure?

Any explanation appreciated.

Comment: Review the definition of a simple closed curve and see if $f\circ \gamma$ saitsfies it. (PS: $\gamma'$ is not good notation here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is Yes, and the details are as follows.  If the curve $f(\gamma)$ failed to be simple, it would have a self-intersection, 
$$
f(\gamma(t_{1})) = f(\gamma(t_{2})), \quad t_{1} \neq t_{2}
$$
and then $f$ would fail to be injective, because
$$
\gamma(t_{1}) \neq \gamma(t_{2})
$$
by the simplicity of $\gamma$.  This failure would contradict the bijectivity of $f$.

As for being closed, this means
$$
\gamma(t_{\mbox{start}}) = \gamma(t_{\mbox{end}}),
$$
so
$$
f(\gamma(t_{\mbox{start}})) = f(\gamma(t_{\mbox{end}})).
$$